# Ruby on Railsで使われるレコードという用語について

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby on Railsで使われるレコードという用語の意味がよくわかりません。
例えば、

```
deleteメソッド
```

これは、既存のレコードを削除するためのメソッドという記載がありました。
ユーザーを削除するときなどに使用するメソッドであることは理解しているのですが、既存のレコードという言葉がピンときません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT用語集とか探してみられました？[http://e-words.jp/w/レコード.html](http://e-words.jp/w/%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89.html) とか参考になると思います。
また、ActiveRecordについては、https://railsguides.jp/active_record_basics.html 辺りも見てください。

---

基本的にレコードは、modelのobjectのことです。
つまり、既存のレコードとはDBに格納済みのデータ＝DBに保存済みのmodelです。
では、既存でないレコードとは？新規に作成して、まだDBに保存してないobjectのことですね。

delete methodを実行すると、既存のレコードを削除するのですから、receiverに指定されたobjectに紐づくDBのデータ行を削除するようなsql文が作成され、DBに対して実行されます。